# Insert 2D plane that slices though a 3D Plotly scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a 3D scatterplot in R, and I want to add a surfaces that slices through the X-Z plane (at Y=0). I tried  creating a matrix of 0 values, but no matter how I assign that to plotly, it doesnt seem to change the orientation of the plotted surface.

```
zet = matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
plot_ly() %>% add_surface(y~zet)
```

[image]

Comment: There may be more than one way to make this happen, but the method that I use is with `mesh3d`. However, you'll still run into issues if you don't specify the argument `delaunayaxis`.  For example, `plot_ly(type = "mesh3d", x = c(-10, -10, 10, 10), z = c(-10, 10, 10, -10), y = c(0, 0, 0, 0), delaunayaxis = "y")`. BTW, if you want a plane on x, I think you have to set `delaunayaxis = "z"` (and the flip for the z-axis).